# iOS 10 : CSS styles not being applied on class change

Tags: ios, css, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am using ionic with angular to create an app for Android and iOS.  On android everything is working fine.  iOS is the problem (of course).

I am applying a class change to an element using `ng-class`.  I can see the class change in the safari inspector in the HTML and the CSS.  But I do not see the changes on the screen.  The only way I can see the change is if I were to manipulate the CSS selector (as simple as turning on/off a style).

Here's the HTML with Angular:

```
<div class="avatar-view__initial__question question-hide" ng-class="{'question-show': speech.captured === true, 'question-hide': speech.captured === false}">{{question.text}}</div>
```

and the CSS

```
  .avatar-view__initial__question {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #E9EBEF;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(../img/icons/icon-ear.svg);
    background-size: 50px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 10px center;
    flex-shrink:1;
    @extend .css-animate;

    &.question-show {
      padding: 20px 10px 20px 60px;
      height: auto !important;
    }
    &.question-hide {
      height:0 !important;
      padding:0 10px 0 60px;
    }
  }
```

As I mentioned, the CSS **IS** being applied, though I can not view the change until I manipulate the any style (pertaining to the element) in the inspector.

Is this a bug? or something I can work around?

**UPDATE**  I just tried this on an iOS 9 device and it works perfectly.  It seems to be a 10 problem.

**UPDATE 2** I feel like it's a flexbox problem.  I had them filling the screen as a column, but I was giving the bottom one zero height when it had no content in it.  It was acting funny.  I reformatted the html to make it work differently.  But I'd like to keep this out there in case someone else is having this issue.

Comment: Any workaround?

Comment: Something that may be influencing this behavior, I'm using **WKWebView**. @ntgCleaner you were also using **WKWebView** or **UIWebView**?

Comment: Hi, can you please provide a codepen or jsfiddle so we can test it on iOS directly. Thanks

Comment: Which version of ionic you are using?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand it's an issue of the iOS 10 webview not re-rendering the template, even though the class has correctly changed and been applied.

So what we want to achieve is enforce a template re-render on class change. We know that the class changes every time the object member `speech.captured` changes value.

So we could enforce re-render when whenever this value changes by adding a conditionally rendered empty span like this:

```html
<span *ngIf="speech.captured"></span>

<div class="avatar-view__initial__question question-hide" ng-class="{'question-show': speech.captured === true, 'question-hide': speech.captured === false}">{{question.text}}</div>
```

Comment: This seemed like a great solution, I was quickly implementing it in my situation. But for my sadness the behavior has become even stranger, since the styles still do not have the effect applied to the view (in my case I add a class to an element and the class appears there and its style in the style tree also, just not applied the view) and the span in question created based (with ngIf) on the same variable that adds the class, is created. In my case I put a value span to see the result more clearly.

Comment: Other details I noticed is that this problem only occurs on items that are visible only with scrolling. And also the style is updated after any scroll in the view.

Answer (score 0):

may be the problem of `cache` storing in browser.just try disabling `cache` and check

Comment: Unfortunately, it wasn't a cache problem.  I disabled the cache and had the same effect.  I want to say it's a bug.  I've reformatted the code to work a different way.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.avatar-view__initial__question {
   text-align: left;
   background-color: #E9EBEF;
   font-size: 1.5em;
   position: relative;
   background-image: url(../img/icons/icon-ear.svg);
   background-size: 50px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: 10px center;
   flex-shrink:1;
   @extend .css-animate;
 }

.avatar-view__initial__question.question-show {
   padding: 20px 10px 20px 60px;
   height: auto !important;
 }
.avatar-view__initial__question.question-hide {
   height:0 !important;
   padding:0 10px 0 60px;
 }
```

Comment: What does this make different from the css of the question? And why would that work? Explain your answer better.

Comment: I don't know exactly what going on but i get stack with same problem, then i try this with working perfectly

Comment: But is your code exactly the same as the one for the question? Either you confused the posted code or it does not make the least sense. Can you take a look, and see what your code has to differ from the question?